# Fifa 12 Pro Clubs: how can we prevent horrible passes by our keeper?

Tags: fifa-12

I've been playing Pro Clubs with my friends and doing fine. One thing that really bothers me is that sometimes the keeper just passes short to a centerback even if there is a opponent standing right there, even when he is between the GK and CB.

We lost a cup game like that; it went to penalties because they got that kind of goal, the kind where the keeper just passed it straight to the opposition and they of course scored.

Can we somehow ensure that the GK doesn't do this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played Pro Clubs, but on Virtual Pro career mode (i.e. just playing as my Virtual Pro against the AI) I've found that if I call for the ball from the GK by pressing the pass button, usually the GK will pass it to the defender right in front of him, who will then pass it to me. If I don't call for it, the GK usually boots it up the field. So maybe you or your friends were calling for a pass?

If not it sounds like a bug where they haven't taken into account online players' tendency to stand right in front of the central defender for goal kicks - something that the AI never does.

Comment: Yeah just lost another game like this last night. It was a game we were pounding on the goalie and they got one lucky like this so off to penalties and lost.